# I can't paint anymore! Beginner here

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am desperate for help :pensive: I am new with blender and atm working with 2.8.
I have a problem while painting. I already know about UVs, unwrapping, saving the image and adding it through the image texture so I can paint on the UV. 
I don't know what I did (I probably did something, for the error to occur) but suddenly I can't paint anymore... Nothing works and I can't even paint on the object itself, all I get is some weird colors. Please help me, I am trying google for an hour, nothing helped:cry: [image]

I made an edit to show you how it looks when I try to paint, maybe it will make it clearer.[image]

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  make sure that the picture is packed: File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend

Comment: What i do in weird paint situations: I start a new blend file, test paint on a default cube, then append my object from previous file to test that. It is possible that there is something strange going on like a brush mask texture being turned on without anything linked so that it just doesn't paint, also could be a memory issue popping up - but check in a new file to see if you can paint there. Maybe save your paint brush so that you can also append that to the new file.

Comment: @CraigDJones Here is an update, thank you for your reply.

Comment: Looks like your GPU driver crash, did you update your driver with the latest one?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean I wouldn't be able to color anything anywhere? Yet if I open a new project and import the model inside it, I can keep painting. Also if the GPU crashed is there a way to recover it / reload the default settings and not be forced to recreate a project every single time?

Comment: If that is a problem with the gpu or its driver it won't affect your file. You say it works when you start a new project ? if so there is nothing wrong with the computer or even blender.

Comment: Pictures look like there is a texture in a loop, like painting with the up mapped texture as a texture mask or texture brush. Can you look to see if you have the same texture showing in these two places as your brush, also can you switch paint tools to Fill and see if that works?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to determine what's happening just from those screenshots, hence moonboots's comment requesting that you upload the broken file which demonstrates the strange behavior.
I've not seen a texture paint problem quite like this before. It may be caused by an unreported bug, perhaps due to some combination of your hardware and a new part of Blender's 2.80's viewport.

As it's unknown territory, the only advice available here will be either A) trying to diagnose what's really going on (i.e. asking many clarification questions); B) suggestions for working around it (eg as Craig D Jones suggests); or, C) if it's happening too consistently to ignore, you might consider submitting a bug report.

Before any of that: experimental builds of Blender are available to download, which are effectively daily updated '2.80+' with additional fixes and some newer features. You might want to try [downloading the bleeding edge latest version](https://builder.blender.org/download/), and see if the same problem still occurs in that.

Finally, if the problem is still happening, please consider using the Help > Report a Bug option. This option uploads operating system and graphics cards details which help pinpoint things with much less guesswork.
If you can find and describe the fewest steps to reproduce the error from a blank starting state, consistently (i.e. more than once) then that's invaluable for the devs to pinpoint it quickly if it is a new bug.
I know this doesn't help you immediately fix your problem today, but if this is something unreported, reporting it is the best way to get it resolved and then gone from the newest version.